# LinkedIn Marketing API - averageDailyReachMetrics vs approximateUniqueImpressions question

Tags: linkedin-api

Recently it was announced that approximateUniqueImpressions is going to be deprecated and replaced by averageDailyReachMetrics (as long as the request is grouped by campaign). I have been fetching approximateUniqueImpressions grouped by creatives for business delivery. Is there any alternative for approximateUniqueImpressions for requests grouped by creatives?